# Different ways to get Google Api-Key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-messaging, api-key

I want to use GCM and Google Maps in my android app, and therefore I need an Google Api-Key. Now I noticed, that there are two different ways of getting this key:

1. The Google Developer Console, where I have to type in the ApplicationId/PackageName, and the SHA1 Fingerprint.
2. This Site: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue
   But there, I don't have to put in an SHA1 Fingerprint, I just fill in the Name, and the package name (which is besides very confusing, I thought Google divided the package name and the applicationId, and the applicatonId is the stuff, which uniquely identifies your app), and get the Id for GCM and an API-Key

Now, how is it possible, that the one way you don't have to fill in an Fingerprint, and the other way you are obligated to. I mean, when you swith from debug certificate to your own one, you also have to get a new Api-Key, because your Fingerprint chaged, is this even neccessary the second way?
I hope you can order this all a bit for me.

Answer (score 0):

I never had to actually fingerprint. I followed the instructions on this website and got the free API key.Then I made my app using google maps and an IFRAME. Here is the link to help. Hopefully it can help you out...they pretty much just gave me a key after creating a project.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: But this is for Websites, isn`t it? My question reffered to an android application.

Comment: ah i didnt read that part...my apologies. Although the key may work, but I am unsure. Are you using Android Studio? I know you can create a google maps project there.

Comment: I'm looking at it a way, but they all lead to "signing" your app...which then leads to the finger print procedures at one time or another.

Comment: Mh, did you try the link in the second possbilitie? There you do not have to provide the fingerprint.
Ah, it seems, that the Api-Key you get the second way, is for the server, not for the app. But it also works fine for the app, what is really odd.